# Getting 0 using AVERAGEIF function in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a column of 1011 rows of values (E1 is header) and some of them are blank, I want to fill those blank cells by the mean of all other non-empty cells in that column.(filled cells and blank cells are in the same column, no 0 in the column).So I tried this function in one of the blank cells:

```
=AVERAGEIF(E$2:E$1012,"<>")
```

I got 0 using this function.Can I only calculate the value on other cells and put it back to the blank cells?

I have searched for a while how people use AVERAGEIF function and I think my problem is because the range includes the cell with the formula itself, causing infinite self referencing loop.As i can see people are all using this funtion in other row than the range.

Comment: You are correct in that your formula will create a circular reference. Create a new column, or use VBA

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip blank cells, you can simply use the `AverageA()` function, no need to write an `AverageIf()` for this.

Comment: How would the result differ from a simple `AVERAGE` function?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld: you're right: I had tested `AverageA()` with the values 1, 2, <BLANK> and 3 and I got 2. I thought that the normal `Average()` would yield 1.5 but it also gave 2, so indeed, a simple `Average()` can be used too.

Comment: @Dominique I have tried a bit, AverageA() also needs to be done on another column, right?

Comment: Not in another column, but I would advise you not to have your cell with the formula in your input range, that would cause a circular reference and I also don't see the sense of this.